# What happens if you downvote a post while you have 125 reputation?

Tags: discussion

The requirement to downvote posts is 125 reputation what happens if you downvote a post while you have 125 reputation (it would subtract 1 reputation) would you lose privileges to downvote? also if you undownvote do you get reputation back? I'm just kinda curious.